# How to create a `ContentType` model object through a model class in Django?

Tags: python, django, model

I'm using django 1.6

I have a model that have a `ForeignKey` field refering to the kernel `ContentType` model:

```
class AuthEvent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, verbose_name='授权用户')
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='授权状态')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='授权时间')
    # Look at this field!
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name='授权类型', null=True)

    @classmethod
    def make_auth(cls, user, tp=None):
        # question here!
        # I want to obtain a ContentType object refering to the tp model class
        cls.objects.create(user=user, content_type=(tp)
```

---

For example, I have a `class A(models.Model)`, how can I get a `ContentType` object refering to the model class A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, I thought it to be a `classmethod` or `staticmethod` before, but found it to be a Factory Method on Manager:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)
>>> user_type
<ContentType: user>
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttypemanager